# Is this question a library recommendation question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, not-constructive

My impression of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926984/python-template-system-for-publishing-static-files#comment20945570_14926984) is that it is asking for a [library recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) (for a templating library in Python). My reasoning is that it is asking for a feature that is provided by many libraries, without giving a particular reason to judge that certain libraries would solve his problem better than others would.

The OP disagrees, a couple of users answered (including myself originally), and others haven't voted to close. Thus, I'm asking whether this actually is a "Not Constructive" library recommendation question, and if it's not, what distinguishes it?

Comment: Not constructive in my book.

Comment: Even though your answer is largely composed of a link to a list, it's a good response in a way, since it short-circuits the procession of "Use X." "Use Y." answers that are the reason library recommendation questions should be closed. I almost think you should undelete it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: That's an interesting point. I went ahead and undeleted it. I suppose the OP could accept it if he likes.